# How can I inject CDI event with HK2 in JUnit Test?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara, hk2

I would like to test my Jakarta application (Payara) with simply JUnit Test (without arquillian, without MicroShed).

I use ServiceLocator from Hk2 to inject service and its work well for my JPA entity and Service.

```
private static ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

@BeforeAll
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
    serviceLocator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();
    ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(
            serviceLocator,
            EntityManagerHK2Factory.class,
            ProducerUtils.class,
            FishService.class,
            ShopRepository.class,
            Family.class, Fish.class, FishStockKey.class, Shop.class, Stock.class, WaterType.class);
}

@Test
public void it_should_sell_fish() {
    //GIVEN
    FishService fishService = serviceLocator.getService(FishService.class);
    String shopName = "Magic Fish";
    String fishName = "Scalaire";
    int quantity = 3;
    //WHEN
    float bill = fishService.sell(shopName, fishName, quantity);
    //THEN
    assertThat(bill, is(54f));
}
```

But I have some issues since I had include CDI event inside my FishService.

```
@Inject
private Event<StockEvent> stockEvent;
```

And then I fire an event.

When I launch the test serviceLocator does not manage to create the FishService and I get the following error:

```
A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=Event<StockEvent>,parent=FishService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,976949492)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.meynier.jakarta.service.FishService errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.meynier.jakarta.service.FishService
```

In this test class I don't want to test the event CDI feature.

How can I use Hk2 to inject the CDI event service ?
(My code is host in this [github account](https://github.com/BaptisteMeynier/Jakarta-Article/blob/junit_event_with_hk2/src/test/java/com/meynier/jakarta/InjectionTest.java))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org) to mock the `Event` and then bind the mock with an `AbstractBinder` and add that to the `ServiceLocator`. Here's a complete test

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class Hk2CdiInjectTest {

    public interface Event<T> {
        T get();
    }

    public interface StockEvent {
        String getStock();
    }

    public static class Service {

        @Inject
        private Event<StockEvent> event;

        public String getStock() {
            return event.get().getStock();
        }
    }

    private static ServiceLocator locator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(locator, Service.class);

        final Event<StockEvent> event = (Event<StockEvent>) mock(Event.class);
        final StockEvent stockEvent = mock(StockEvent.class);
        when(stockEvent.getStock()).thenReturn("GOOGL UP!");
        when(event.get()).thenReturn(stockEvent);
        Binder eventBinder = new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(event).to(new TypeLiteral<Event<StockEvent>>() {});
            }
        };
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(locator, eventBinder);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        Service service = locator.getService(Service.class);

        assertThat(service.getStock()).isEqualTo("GOOGL UP!");
    }
}
```